# AutoRest generated client won't compile - Cannot resolve RequestContext

Tags: swagger, autorest

When generating a client the resulting package appears to have all the necessary packages.  The code references RequestContext, which is part of Azure.Core, but neither Visual Studio 2022 nor Rider can resolve it.

I'm hesitant to add our org's Swagger file.  Fortunately this occurs even when using the example yaml file from the autorest repo: [Petstore.Yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/autorest/main/Samples/openapi-v3/1a-code-generation-minimal/petstore.yaml)

My settings are pretty basic: `autorest --input-file=petstore.yaml --csharp --namespace=Petstore --output-folder=Client`

I am using the current version of Autorest (3.7.0) with extensions:
`@autorest/csharp: (latest->3.0.0-beta.20240116.1) @autorest/modelerfour: (4.26.0->4.26.0)`

There must be a package or setting I'm missing, but I have not found any documentation related to this issue.